# javascript breathing element - Animation seems to act up after long period of time

Tags: javascript

So this is my first code snippet that I wrote for fun as part of an exercise. I created a 300 × 300 px box where two corners have their `border-radius` increased and decreased to create a breathing animation. After a couple of minutes, the animations seem to speed up and flutter. 
Does anyone have any idea how to improve the code?

```
function frame() {
  var elem   = document.getElementById('box1');
  var radius = 0;
  var id1    = setInterval(frame1, 20);
  var id2    = setInterval(frame2, 20);

  function frame1() {
    if (radius == 300) {
      clearInterval(id1);
      setInterval(frame2, 20);
    } else {
      clearInterval(id2);

      radius ++;

      elem.style.borderTopRightRadius   = radius + 'px';
      elem.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = radius + 'px';
    }

    return radius;
  }

  function frame2() {
    if (radius == 0) {
      clearInterval(id2);
      setInterval(frame1, 20);
    } else {
      clearInterval(id1);

      radius --;

      elem.style.borderTopRightRadius   = radius + 'px';
      elem.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = radius + 'px';
    }

    return radius;
  }
}

frame()
```

Comment: *"After a couple of minutes..."* Did you make that tab inactive at any time in those couple of minutes? Timers are slowed down and/or sometimes skipped while tabs are inactive. You have two timers, and the delays may not impact them perfectly equally. Better to use a single timer, and to determine where you are in the animation by looking at how much time has passed since your last call (since it may be **much** longer than the interval you've specified).

Comment: Assign `id1` and `id2` new interval IDs inside `frame1()` and `frame2()`: `id1 = setInterval(frame1, 20)`. At the moment you are generating new intervals without clearing them.

Comment: use `requestAnimationFrame` and base your animation on elapsed time instead

Comment: Changing DOM elements with javascript is very "heavy" for browser. Maybe try using `keyframes`: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using requestAnimationFrame and basing the animation on elapsed time, and some dirty maths

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
var radius = 0;
var begin;
function frame(v) {
    if(begin === undefined) {
        begin = v;
    }
    let radius = Math.abs((300 + (v - begin) / 20) % 600 - 300);
    elem.style.borderTopRightRadius = radius + "px";
    elem.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = radius + "px";
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}
requestAnimationFrame(frame);
```

```css
#box1 {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
</div>
```

> But CSS animation is probably better for such a simple animation

```css
#box1 {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:dodgerblue;
}
#box1 {
    animation:breath 6s infinite linear alternate;
}
@keyframes breath {
    from { border-radius: 0 0 0 0; }
    to { border-radius: 0 300px 0 300px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
</div>
```

Here's the above two methods, side by side

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("box1");
var radius = 0;
var begin;
var maxRadius = 100;
var x = 60;
function frame(v) {
    if(begin === undefined) {
        begin = v;
    }
    let radius = Math.abs((maxRadius + (v - begin) / x) % (maxRadius *2) - maxRadius);
    elem.style.borderTopRightRadius = radius + "px";
    elem.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = radius + "px";
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}
requestAnimationFrame(frame);
```

```css
#box1 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:dodgerblue;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
}


#box2 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:dodgerblue;
    display:inline-block;
}
#box2 {
    animation:breath 6s infinite linear alternate;
}
@keyframes breath {
    from { border-radius: 0 0 0 0; }
    to { border-radius: 0 50% 0 50%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
</div>
<div id="box2">
</div>
```

Both methods should be immune to any timing issues due to tab being in background etc

Comment: Thank you. I like both solutions although I probably will be using the CSS solution, because it is more straightforward and easier to use. On JavaScript solution I just don´t understand the math and i don´t want to use something I don´t understand.

Comment: the math is easy really - I just haven't figured out what `x` is :p

Comment: x is basically interval.
Could you explain the math to me please ?